# Drupal 7 WYSIWYG Editor Auto Spell Check

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

My team and I are trying to have the SCAYT (Spell check as you type) feature in the WYSIWYG bar to be automatically enabled, so that we can make our users' jobs easier for them as many of them have requested this. Currently, people are able to enable it in the editor manually. We'd like it so that it's automatically working once they start typing.

I've looked up the TinyMCE module, but it's severely out of date and we won't be using that. I tried to fumble with the code to no avail. I've read different forum but they are all out of date.

Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated and if more information is needed I'll be happy to provide it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [CKEditor](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor) is a very popular Drupal editor that already has a built in SCAYT as you can see [here](http://ckeditor.com/features), as well as many other plugins and extensions.

Comment: We've been using the WYSIWYG editor, and we have customized it too much to change it now. Which is why I'm asking if there's anything I can do with the editor we're using. Thank you, though, for your answer.

Comment: Often [WYSIWYG](https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) is a facilitator to add other editors: `Allows the use of client-side editors to edit content. It simplifies the installation and integration of the editor of your choice.` Are you sure you are using this module alone, and no editor is configured?

Comment: I can make it work when I enable CKeditor, but it makes our WYSIWYG editor look like it has no CSS. Any idea why that would happen?